# How to merge array of objects with a property at any level in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

Here is my array objects

```
var skus = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "active": true,
    "attributes": {
      "color": "pink",
      "size": "small",
      "material": "plastic"
    },
    "price": 899
  },{
    "id": "2",
    "object": "sku",
    "active": true,
    "attributes": {
      "color": "blue",
      "size": "medium",
      "material": "plastic"
    },
    "price": 500
  },{
    "id": "3",
    "object": "sku",
    "active": true,
    "attributes": {
      "color": "blue",
      "size": "medium",
      "material": "metal"
    },
    "price": 600
  }
]
```

I want the output something like this :

```
finalOutput = {
  "plastic" : [{id:1,...},{id:2,...}],
  "metal" : [{id:3,...}]
}
```

So basically, I want to merge all the objects which have same attributes.material value.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research. [Search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO. Attempt to do the work. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. *(not my dv)*

Comment: @NinaScholz No. I was thinking to use lodash library, but i'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Just an attempt for your case. May be it helps you. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h5nksjdz/)

Comment: @MohammadUsman ... if you refine your approach, you might switch from a generic [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) iteration to a generic iterating [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Counting_instances_of_values_in_an_object) (data) transformation.

Comment: @WaseemAhmed ... in case you read Usman's *fiddle* approach do not take it as the final answer since it does not fully fit your requirements. You were asking for a generically working approach - *... with a property at any level in javascript?*

Answer (score 0):

Use lodash's [`_.groupBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy) to collect the objects by their `attributes.material`.

```js
var skus = [{"id":"1","active":true,"attributes":{"color":"pink","size":"small","material":"plastic"},"price":899},{"id":"2","object":"sku","active":true,"attributes":{"color":"blue","size":"medium","material":"plastic"},"price":500},{"id":"3","object":"sku","active":true,"attributes":{"color":"blue","size":"medium","material":"metal"},"price":600}];

var result = _.groupBy(skus, 'attributes.material');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

... ok, let's have a look at [Usman's approach](https://jsfiddle.net/h5nksjdz/) ...

```js
var skus = [{ "id": "1", "active": true, "attributes": { "color": "pink", "size": "small", "material": "plastic" }, "price": 899 }, { "id": "2", "object": "sku", "active": true, "attributes": { "color": "blue", "size": "medium", "material": "plastic" }, "price": 500 }, { "id": "3", "object": "sku", "active": true, "attributes": { "color": "blue", "size": "medium", "material": "metal" }, "price": 600 }];

var obj = {};

skus.forEach(o => {
  if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(o.attributes.material)) {
   obj[o.attributes.material] = [o];
  } else {
   obj[o.attributes.material].push(o);
  }
});

console.log(obj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

... it is based on an external object `obj` that serves both purposes, being the final result but also being the collecting reference for the time of iterating the given data structure `skus`.

Then there is a lookup for an existing property/key on `obj` that does match the value of a certain substructure of `skus`. In case `obj` does not yet features this key, an array gets assigned to a newly created property. This array already holds a single item, the current object of the `skus` iteration.

If the property already exists - by then it references an array - the current object of the `skus` iteration just will be pushed into this array.

Having finished the `forEach` iteration of `skus`, `obj` will hold one or more lists of former `skus`-items, each mapped to a single key/property of unique `attributes.material`-values derieved from `skus`-items.

A good solution provides a function that encloses all of this code.

An even better solution will come up with a more generic and better reusable approach. Since the whole matter is about transforming list based data structures, [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) are good candidates for it. Here the latter is the right one for `map` only is capable of mapping one list item into just another one, thus it does not change the list itself but it transforms each of a list's items. `reduce` is far more flexible for it provides into it's callback a collector/accumulator object in addition to the currently iterated item. This collector can be provided as initial value and it's type/structure is free of choice.

A `reduce` based approach that meets the OP's requirements needs to be customizable in terms of how to access a certain property that's value then is base of a (gouped) list of objects that share this special property value.

A working example then might look like the next provided one ...

```js
var skus = [{ "id": "1", "active": true, "attributes": { "color": "pink", "size": "small", "material": "plastic" }, "price": 899 }, { "id": "2", "object": "sku", "active": true, "attributes": { "color": "blue", "size": "medium", "material": "plastic" }, "price": 500 }, { "id": "3", "object": "sku", "active": true, "attributes": { "color": "blue", "size": "medium", "material": "metal" }, "price": 600 }];


function collectItemGroupedByGenericKey(collector, item) {
  var
    groupKey    = collector.getGroupKey(item),
    store       = collector.store,
    storedList  = store[groupKey];

  if (!storedList) {
    storedList = store[groupKey] = [];
  }
  storedList.push(item);

  return collector;
}


var materialList = skus.reduce(collectItemGroupedByGenericKey, {

  getGroupKey:  function (item) { return item.attributes.material; },
  store:        {}

}).store;

console.log('materialList : ', materialList);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```